# Is there an efficient algorithm for solving tiling puzzles?

Tags: algorithms, tiling

As an example of the type of problem, consider Stewart Coffin's Cruiser puzzle:

> Let R be a 48 × 31 rectangle. Let T be a 30°-60°-90° triangle with
>   hypotenuse 34.565 (so legs are 17.2825 and 29.934). Let P be a right
>   trapezoid with base 20.0982 and altitudes 27.1178 and 15.514. Show how
>   to place two copies of T and two copies of P inside R with no overlap.

[image: Pieces for the cruiser puzzle]

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jESRD.jpg)

The algorithm should be able to solve for any number of polygons of any shape within another polygon of any shape (or conclude that such a solution is not possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[*Tiling figures of the plane with two bars*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/092577219400015N) shows that this problem is NP-complete in the general case. Simply have the horizontal and vertical bar the same size $\geq 3$.

Comment: What does "greater than 3" mean?